# Content Organizer Rules in SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-organizer, content-organizer-rule

I am using content organizer to route the documents based on specific column property.

iIt is working fine on the upload process but not in the case when I update the properties after upload.

Can anyone share your thoughts around this problem?

Comment: When you upload an event handler will route the docs immediately. When you modify something you will have to wait for the content organizer timer job to run. It should run daily.

Comment: being an online version, can we change it to run at our own times ? running it daily once is not a good solution for this.

Comment: Unfortunately not.

Answer (score 0):

So I was trying to find an answer to this problem as I had a workflow running to assign specific properties to the document based on user entered properties.

In then end I created a workflow that copied the document out to a different library once it had prepared all the properties, another workflow would then run a check on it and send it back to the drop off library where the content organizer rule would kick straight in.

It would be much easier if the Content Organizer rules ran at least hourly.

Comment: I'm stealing this idea - I'm doing a similar thing atm where I need CO to work on updates as well as upload. Agree the way timer jobs can't be changed is a serious drawback sometimes.

Comment: I actually changed this again since, it turns out a workflow moving a file also doesn't trigger a content organizer rule. Now I run a background console app which uses CSOM to update all the metadata once a day around 6pm. The Content organizer rules then runs once a night.

Comment: That's such a messy solution just because Microsoft have shafted timer jobs. I think I'm gonna have to ditch CO from my solution if that's the case - pretty sure the client won't accept once a day as enough.